# Formatting Date from JSON to Datepicker field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, datepicker

After studying I've learned JSON has no standard date literal, which surprised me. I've checked my code and database and it looks like the problem I have is the JSON portion and getting that to appear as MM/DD/YYYY in the datepicker field.

The start value of data.BoardStart is: `"/Date(1454519004200)/"`

So I'm parsing it using: `var BoardStart = new Date(parseInt(data.BoardStart.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));`

This outputs it to a something like `wed feb 03 2016 10:03:24 gmt-0700 (mountain standard time)`

This results in an error: `BoardStart.format("MM-DD-YYYY");`

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format a Microsoft JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: @DanielA.White No, the OP already figured out how to make a `Date` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because there is no `format` method on a `Date` object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

You have to write your own formatting code or use a library like http://momentjs.com/

```js
var jsonDate = "/Date(1454519004200)/"

var BoardStart = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));

console.log(moment(BoardStart).format('MM-DD-YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```